# Tell for an entity, whether there is an entity belonging to it that belongs to others too

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a junction table showing which countries (`c`) have been visited by which persons (`p`):

```
+---+---+
| c | p |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

I'm looking for a query that tells for a given country whether it's been visited by someone who has visited another country too. So in this example, this query should return true for countries 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty is more about how you want to see the results, assuming we can just concat them:

```
select string_agg(c::text,',')
from foo
group by p
having count(distinct c) > 1
```

DBFiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8b81477bbf205f3792756e53bf03e22a

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
SELECT c 
FROM tbl
WHERE p IN (SELECT p 
            FROM tbl 
            GROUP BY p 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c) > 1)
```